# HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

Tags: node.js, firebase

First of all i am trying to learn using Firebase functions. So i had installed node.js a long time ago and today i tried to use a notification function on firebase.So when i used firebase init in command prompt it asked me to proceed and then asked me what do i want to do so i chose functions there. So far everything was fine but then it stopped suddenly and showed me

```
Error: HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected 
OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

i tried searching for it online but couldn't find any solution so I came here. Any help would be appreciated.i am confused as what is the problem here.

Answer (score 70):

face the same problem
solved by logging out then login again

```
firebase logout
```

then

```
firebase login
```

A shortcut would be

```bash
firebase login --reauth
```

Comment: That's a great answer! I love this answer! :) And it helped for me too, even though I was still logged in since long ago. They've changed the login method, I see. That must be why.

Comment: Helped a lot! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Note if you are using wsl or wsl2 then make sure your system clock is in sync: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4245

Comment: Thank you! I had turned off time/zone sync today after travelling (because windows couldn't update my time/zone automatically). This fixed it, once I turned on Sync Windows time (even though my machine time is showing incorrect time...).